# Make Visual Studio 2010 place C++ pre-processor directives in .h files by default?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, preprocessor

I believe this to be possible as I'm sure I've seen Visual Studio create .h files with `#ifdef/#ifndef` pre-processor directives already included before but for some reason my installation doesn't include them. I find it tedious to type them out myself, any ideas why it isn't just including those directives? It's not the express version either.

I may have changed a setting in the past without realizing it, that's a possibility, anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: Why it need? Use just #pragma once, because this definition supports most compilators.

Comment: Because I didn't know about pragma, I now do, thanks. I'd still prefer it handle monotonous tasks like that by itself but for the time being I will switch to your suggested solution.

Comment: Such files are generated by the wizards included in Visual Studio, the ones that auto-generate code.  You are the wizard if you need your own header file.  If you create them so often that this gets to be a chore then you are doing it wrong.  VS2012 supports snippets.

Comment: I'm well aware I don't need to create them so often but I'm in a class and they are essentially forcing overuse of headers for a certain project.